# Global exposure | jQuery vs. Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Backbone exposes itself in the first 50 lines or so of code.

JQuery in the last 50 lines of code or so.

Why the difference?

Is this just random developer choosing.  Or is there a purpose I don't see here.

[Github Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1424)

```
Backbone = root.Backbone = {}; // line 33
```

[JQuery Latest](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js)

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery; // near bottom..can someone post github link
```

Comment: How can I find the link to jQuery on github...i like github formatting

Answer (score 2):

Backbone seems to use object prototyping and applies features/functions afterwards.

jQuery seems to create a closure and expose it to the global scope later, because there is the possibility to not expose "$" but only "jQuery" in the noConflict-Mode. This seems to also make sure that the "ready"-Event is not run too early before all the action is defined since JS can have some tricky race-conditions with its callbacks...

Comment: I don't completely understand what you are getting at...both libraries have a no-conflict mode...I can see that it makes sense to make sure all the code has been read before exposing it, in general...perhaps..this should be standard...Is there any reason for Backbone, not to wait until the end?

Comment: Backbone itselft does not fire any event like the ready-Event jQuery fires. It just provides functions to be used by others. jQuery does this, too, but not only this.

Backbone creates a Library for maintaining JS-Objects (roughly said), while jQuery provides DOM-Manipulation-API (also roughly). Backbone is ready when it's loaded. jQuery needs to fire events when DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Developer choice based on deployment context.

- Backbone (and more notably Underscore) is written as a more general purpose JavaScript library which is designed to be optionally available for server side (Node.js) or otherwise external to browser uses.  The context that it works within is therefore more variable and it's attachment to that context is more pliable for use with things like common.js and require.js. There is therefore a focus earlier on in the surrounding context and less on the availability of the library itself, particularly since Backbone is used in environments where namespaces will generally be more defined and customized (including rich browser apps where the developer will be more actively involved in those concerns).
- jQuery is designed with the intent of being used within a Web browser.  The context is therefore fixed, and jQuery can go about building a library within a namespace.  The focus for jQuery then switches to being readily available and easy to use at a particular location (like `$` or `jQuery`) while allowing for avoiding conflicts within the often polluted browser environment: originally providing a lifeline in a mess rather than fitting in with a larger structured environment (as demonstrated by how it becomes the guardian for plugins rather than promoting higher modularity).

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Backbone was made to work on the server-side or the client side. jQuery was made to work in a DOM environment where a global window object must exists. In a server side environment like Node, the global object is called `global`.

You were close but the actual part in the Backbone source that sets this is actually the first 2 lines and the last line:

```
(function(){
  var root = this;

  ...
}).call(this);
```

Like most framework, Backbone starts with an anonymous function to encapsulate its setup, but in this case it calls that method in the context of the global scope `this` which resolves to `window` in a web client and `global` on a serverside like node.

Note that jQuery probably doesn't do something like this because it relies on dozens of DOM methods like `document.getElementById`. It is possible however, to create a virtual DOM enviornment on the serverside to load jQuery in. See projects like [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Here are slides of a talk I gave where I cover this exact topic:
https://speakerdeck.com/krunkosaurus/deep-dive-into-backbone-dot-js-internals-plus-underscore-dot-js